# How to use @output to fire a boolean from child to parent

Tags: angular, output

Hi angular community,

I want to fire an Event using @Output to hide or open/close a div containing others components. It's quite simple but I never use EventEmitter before, so i would like when hideDem is called it hide or open/close the div depending on other propreties comming from the child.ts

child.html:

```
 <img type="button" label="Click" (click)="hideDem()" id="foldup" src="./assets/img/fold_up_blacksmall.png"/>
```

child.comp.ts:

```
@Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public hideDem(): void {
  this.hideMePartially = !this.hideMePartially;
  if (this.hideMePartially) {
    this.open.emit(true);
  } else {
    this.close.emit(false);
  }
}
```

parent.comp.html

```
 <div class="daydetail"> 
<div><my-daydetail [showMePartially]="showVar" ></my-daydetail></div>
  <div [hidden]="(close)=hideDem($event)">
    <div>
       <app-pie-chart [minifiedMe]="hideMeup" ></app-pie-chart>
     </div>
     <div>
       <app-fonctionnaly [minifiedMe]="hideMeup"></app-fonctionnaly>
     </div>
     <div>
       <app-my-verticalchart [minifiedMe]="hideMeup" ></app-my-verticalchart>
     </div>
     <div>
       <app-dysfonction [showMePartially]="hideVar"></app-dysfonction>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- End of hidden-->
</div> <!-- End of daydetail-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
[hidden]="(close)=hideDem($event)"
```

is invalid markup. `(close)` can't be inside the expression of another binding.

```html
<my-daydetail [showMePartially]="showVar" 
    (close)="isHidden = true" (open)="isHidden = false"></my-daydetail>
  <div [hidden]="isHidden">
```

Comment: thanks to help me I have no errors in the console when I used `<div  [hidden]="isHidden" (close)="hideDem($event)">` but I doesn't hide my component inside the div..any idea why?

Comment: What element exactly should be hidden, and what exactly should cause it to be hidden?

Comment: app-fonctionnaly, app-my-verticalchart and app-dysfonction should be hidden when I clicked a button in child.html the button look like that ==>   <img type="button" label="Click" (click)="hideDem()" id="foldup" src="./assets/img/fold_up_blacksmall.png"/>

Comment: What's the selector of child.comp?

Comment: <my-daydetail></my-daydetail> but that component is already fired from the parent earlier in the code like so ==>  `<div><my-daydetail [showMePartially]="showVar" ></my-daydetail></div>` and I bind it from @input to the child i you know what I mean

Comment: That's not used in the code in your question. I need to know how parent and child are related. Please add the missing code to your question.

Comment: wooow many many thanks Günter its not the first time you put me out of a big hole..I been there since almost a week !!! Next time I pass germany I will brought you a big bottle of Bordeaux !

Comment: according to code from that post I would like to do the same with a subchild and an output to the child..I've tried to adapt your code since two days now but doesn't work for that case..I've tried to explain in that post but without success https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369561/binding-a-child-from-two-differents-parents-in-angular-4